# Where did Nitrogen come from in the Universe?

Tags: astrophysics

Does nitrogen come from nucleosynthesis or spallation?

Comment: Well, if from spallation, how would whatever it spallates off of be formed might be one good question. You should google the 'CNO cycle'.

Comment: I was looking for and answer, something like "Carbon is formed in giant stars, supper giant stars, nucleosynthesis". So the answer is "The catalytic cycle"?

Comment: Carbon can be made in the triple-alpha process, and once you have it you can go through the CNO cycle.